# GAE - mail API - dialy limits

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail
a GAE app developed by a third party (anyone of us) and hosted in GA Cloud has a limit of 20.000 messages that can send each day, right ?

What if an app has registered 100.000 end-users that accepted to receive a daily email notification ?

isnt GAE a platform for this kind of apps ? do we have to find out for another provider ?
does the app must use a third-party service like mailchimp api or similar to do this job ?

thanks,
d.-

Answer (score 4):

GAE no longer supports sending more than 100 emails and they will not increase your quota using this form request. They are nudging people to SendGrid (why SendGrid specifically in unclear). Its an unfortunate reduction in GAE capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

They have a nice little footnote in there that says:

> The new limit of 20,000 messages per day only applies to applications
>   created on or after December 14th, 2012. Applications created before
>   this date will not be subject to this limit, even if they enable
>   billing after December 14th.

You may be able to go around this by converting an old and unused GAE project to send the emails. If you don't have one, you can ask your friends if they do. Pretty much everybody I know has at least one or two dead GAE projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a quota-increase here: http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?&contact_type=AppEngineCPURequest

Explain what you are doing and why you need more of your mail-quota.

Comment: thanks for replying. the problem with this approach is that one (you, me, everyone, the project itself) depends on the google´s will, right ? i am not sure is a platform with this things is a good choice for business. opinions ?